# How to handle when user closes “Physical Location” prompt in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I'm using the Geolocation object and getCurrentPosition().

Have you seen that everytime you use getCurrentPosition Firefox and Chrome prompt these massages?

Chrome:

```
Example.com wants to track your physical location [allow] [deny] [ X close ]
```

Firefox:

```
Example.com wants to know your location [Share Location] [Don't Share] [Close]
```

My question is: How to handle when a user does not "Allow" nor "Deny" location option but instead closes the prompt?

I have this JAVASCRIPT code but it does not work when user closes the prompt:

```
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    onSuccess,
                    onError,
                    {
                        //enableHighAccuracy: true,
                        timeout: 5000
                        //maximumAge: 120000
                    }
                );
                    alert("holaaaa");
            } else {
                alert('Geolocation not supported.');
            }
```

I'm having some problems with that, any help please?

> This question is related with this post:
>   [How to call function when user Allows or Denies access to "Physical Location"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463367/how-to-call-function-when-user-allows-or-denies-access-to-physical-location)

Comment: I have had this issue before and couldn't find any solutions at that time, I doubt there are any solutions even now.

Comment: That behavior is configurable in those browsers. Mine don't even ask, so I never "close the prompt".  Mine are configured to simply always deny.  I would expect "close" to behave the same as "deny".

Comment: @StephenP: If you've configured Chrome to "never ask", it actually immediately fires the `errorCallback` (as if you clicked Deny).  Firefox does nothing.

Comment: @josh = good info to know, Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

The [spec](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#geolocation_interface) is actually pretty quiet on whether or not a callback MUST be executed if the user simply dismisses the request for permission (as opposed to clicking the Deny button):

> For both `getCurrentPosition` and `watchPosition`, the implementation must never invoke the `successCallback` without having first obtained permission from the user to share location. Furthermore, the implementation should always obtain the user's permission to share location before executing any of the `getCurrentPosition` or `watchPosition` steps described above. If the user grants permission, the appropriate callback must be invoked as described above. **If the user denies permission, the `errorCallback` (if present) must be invoked with code `PERMISSION_DENIED`**, irrespective of any other errors encountered in the above steps. The time that is spent obtaining the user permission must not be included in the period covered by the `timeout` attribute of the `PositionOptions` parameter. The `timeout` attribute must only apply to the location acquisition operation.

I'd say that dismissing the permission request is equivalent to denying the request from the standpoint of `getCurrentPosition`.  Clicking Deny is explicit whereas dismissal (clicking the X) is implicit.

Functionally, the difference is that clicking the Deny button means (1) the current request is denied, and (2) the site is blacklisted and the user will never be prompted to share location again for the site; simply dismissing the request only means that the current request is denied – future requests (in future [BROWSINGCONTEXT](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#browsing-context)s—after the page is reloaded)  will prompt again.

In my opinion, Chrome, Firefox, and IE's current behavior is a bug – all three do nothing if the user dismisses the permission request by clicking the X.  The `errorCallback` should be called if the geolocation permission request is dismissed because any further calls to `getCurrentLocation` in the current BROWSINGCONTEXT will silently fail.  (Opera 11.52 behaves 'correctly' because its permission request UI only has Allow/Deny buttons – no X.)

Mozilla has a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=564397) where they say the current behavior is correct and a newer [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591745) open bug that's relevant; [Chromuim also says](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43548) the current behavior is correct.  IE has [a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/669838/geolocation-error-callback-not-called-if-user-closes-popup) *(registration required)*, but oddly, Microsoft closed it as non-reproducable.

This is really something that the W3C Working Group needs to address.  The page should be able to react to the user declining the location permission request – whether permanently denied or just declined for this session by clicking the X.

---

The only thing you can actually do right now to address this situation is setting your own timeout.  Set a timeout in the geolocation request, and then set your error timeout to be longer than that (to allow the user time to react to the request):

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    var etimeout = setTimout(onError, 10000);
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {timeout:5000});
}
function onSuccess(pos) {
    clearTimeout(etimeout);
    // ...
}
function onError(err) {
    clearTimeout(etimeout);
    // Note `err` will actually be undefined if this is the result of our timeout
    // and anything you do here should be undone by `onSuccess` (in case the user
    // took longer than 5 seconds to approve the request; for that reason, you
    // shouldn't display any modal UI from here.

    // ...
}
```

Comment: The specific case of the user dismissing the bar seems to be marked WontFix in both [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=564397) and [Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43548)

Comment: Works in Firefox for me (the popup appears again after hitting the 'x'). But both Chrome (48.0.2564.116 m) and IE11 don't show the popup again without a page refresh