# Using javascript or jQuery, detect if a user denies browser's request to locate computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I am building a website that asks permission to use a person's location using - `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionFound)`.

Using javascript or jQuery, how can I detect if a user *denies* permission, the moment after they deny it?

My code looks something like this -

```
function Geolocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionFound)
}

function positionFound(position, found) {
    if (position.coords) {
    //do stuff
    }
}
```

Part of the problem is, the code after `navigator` is reached before the user accepts or denies permission to use the computer's location.

Comment: Read some docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2Fwindow.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition - the second parameter to `getCurrentPosition` is for a function to be called for errors, receiving an error object with details ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionError )

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call function when user Allows or Denies access to "Physical Location"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463367/how-to-call-function-when-user-allows-or-denies-access-to-physical-location)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPostions` can take two parameters `success, error`

Change your code to:

```
function positionFound(position) {
    // dostuff
}

function positionNotFound(error) {
    // Handle error
}

function Geolocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionFound, positionNotFound)
}
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition)

Answer (score 0):

Ian is right, look at this [example](http://html5demos.com/geo) using `getCurrentPosition`