# Is there a way to return true if the user allows location sharing and false if denied?

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript function that returns true if the user is sharing the location in the site and return false if not.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way for a synchronus call?

Comment: Its depend on how you are asking? share your code of asking about share location

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call function when user Allows or Denies access to "Physical Location"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463367/how-to-call-function-when-user-allows-or-denies-access-to-physical-location)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get city name using geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/get-city-name-using-geolocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    navigator.permissions.query({name: 'geolocation'}).then(function(status) {
      console.log(status);
    });
```